# Update database at runtime with Entity Framework Core 2.x

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to dynamically build some parts of a database, based on the user input. So, for example, the user has the ability to define entities (which will be then mapped to tables) with custom fields (field name and type are inputted by the user at runtime).

To accomplish that, I'm generating on the fly the class of the newly defined entity and add it to the DbContext, so it's tracked.

My first problem is the alignment of the database schema. It would be great if I could use Migrations at runtime (ie: create and execute a migration from C# code), but my understanding is that's not possible.

Also, the user can edit the entities that were defined and, let's say, add/delete a field or modify a field's type. And here the problem is to detect these changes and generate the relevant SQL script to align the database schema.

Does Entity Framework Core 2.x provide something that can help?

Comment: It doesn't sound like SQL Server is best suited to this job. Have you taken a look at NoSQL databases? something like CouchDB, MongoDB or RavenDB. They would be much better suited to this purpose. Half the battle is using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Other solutions are XML fields (similar to NoSQL solution) or solutions where you have an entity to keep Record reference, Configured column name, Value (I thougth that is not a good solution for performance reasons but I see it implemented quite often)